# Kp-fonts package used font

Tags: fonts, kpfonts

Which is the font used in Kp-fonts package? I would to know what's the name of the fonts provided by the `kpfonts` package.
I can't understand if kp-fonts is just package's name or also the font's name!

Comment: It is called `Kp-fonts`, see the `kpfonts` manual. It is a new text and math font defined almost from scratch. If that is not enough, please be a bit more specific.

Comment: run "texdoc kpfonts" or view http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/kpfonts/doc/kpfonts.pdf

Comment: The kp in kpfonts stands for Kepler. It's based on Zapf's Palatino font, but provides many interesting extensions and adaptations.

Comment: @Mico Sounds like an answer to me :-)

Comment: It's inspired by Palatino, with much more features, a few glitches and a letter-spacing that makes every typographer weep.

Answer (score 2):

The "kp" in "kpfonts" stands for (Johnnes) Kepler. The fonts in the `kpfonts` package are based on Hermann Zapf's `Palatino` font, but provide many interesting extensions and adaptations, such as giving easy access to old-style numerals and the *very old-style* "long" form of the letter "s".